# ClassCastException during cast to interface

Tags: osgi, glassfish-4

I'm trying to play with OSGi and I stuck with one problem...
I have simple class FirstVersionPrinter

```
public class FirstVersionPrinter implements VersionPrinter {
private final static String VERSION = "111";

 @Override
 public String printVersion() {
     return VERSION;
 }
}
```

and interface

```
public interface VersionPrinter {
 public String printVersion();
}
```

and Locator class

```
@Override
public String print(Integer version) {

    final BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass()).getBundleContext();
        for (Bundle bundle : bundleContext.getBundles()) {
            BundleContext bundleContext1 = bundle.getBundleContext();
                ServiceReference sr = bundleContext1.getServiceReference(VersionPrinter.class.getName());

            ...
(1)               ((VersionPrinter) bundleContext1.getService(sr)).printVersion());
```

in Locator I'm trying to iterate through bundles and execute printVersion for my VersionPrinter. But in line (1) I got ClassCastException

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: example.FirstVersionPrinter cannot be cast to example.VersionPrinter
```

Could someone clarify why it's happens?
Thanks.

PS: Locator and FirstVersionPrinter in the different bundles

Comment: is it possible that example.VersionPrinter is available in two installed bundles? If you have OSGi console, you can check it easily. If you do not have, you can change your code to check if there are multiple services with the same interface name and from which bundle they come.

Comment: In console there is only one bundle, but in log there are a lot of such ClassCastExceptions from the different bundles like 'org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jms-plugin' or 'org.glassfish.main.connectors.admin'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This always happens if more than one bundle contains the package example. If the "same" class is loaded by two different class loaders then it is not considered to be the same by java.

So make sure you ideally have the interface class only in one bundle and export it from there. All bundles that need the class should import this package.

If for some reason you have to package the example package in more than one bundle make sure that all those bundles import and export the package in their Manifest. This makes sure that OSGi will select only one of the packages for export and import this from all other bundles.

Btw. the way you iterate through the bundles and ask each BundleContext for a service reference is not correct. You only need to use one BundleContext and do context.getServiceReferences to get all you FirstVersionPrinter services.